# How to access file in python flask sent in POST method of my API?

Tags: python, flask, http-post, file-handling

My post request is like this:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/upload
Content-Type: text/csv
Filename: /path/to/file/filename.csv
```

I want to receive this file in my code.I have found that the file is received in `request.files['file']` in case my file is uploaded using html form where the name associated with the uploaded file is `'file'`. But since I am sending the file in the post method of my API, I have no name associated directly to my file object. SO how do I accept the file in my python flask code?

The code I am using is like this but the `request.files`object seems empty after the API hit.

```
class FileInput(Resource):
    def post(self):
        conn = e.connect()
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return "No file part."
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            return "No File Selected"
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return "File Input Successful."
        return "File Input Unsuccessful."
```

Comment: You mean the method always exits where `return "No File Selected"`? Can you add a `print request.files` right at the beginning of the method and share the output?